# how to convert jchart into csv format

Tags: java, csv, charts, qgraphicsview, jchartfx

Please can anyone tell me how to convert a JChart into csv format , so that I can save the chart data into csv format

Answer (score 1):

try getting the column and row count and keys, them access each value 'getValue (int row, int column)' and them export to a file...